# Rails verify if an image is clicked before sending the form

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-5

I am new to Rails and am trying to create a form that submit a value to the database depends on the image clicked.

I have five images and a submit button. I am thinking of turning the five images into button class so that whenever it is clicked, it will run an action in the Article Controller and pass the value.

For example if the first  image is clicked, it will run the action @article.title="First image is clicked" and the submit button will run the Create action of @article.save.

I tried:

```
<%= button_to "Submit Score", { :controller => "articles", :action => "submitScore"} %>
```

but for some reasons when I press the image it tries to run the Create action in the Article Controller and tries to save it as well. I know that because I have some data validation and restricted the @article.title cannot be blank and when I press the image button it says title cannot be blank.

What is the best way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`button_to` generates an entire `form` tag. Try using `button` tags with value attributes contained within a form tag helper:

```
<%= form_for @article, articles_path do |f| %>
  <%= f.text_field :title %> <!-- or hidden field? -->

  <button type="submit" name="article[score]" value="1">
    <%= image_tag 'foobar.gif' %>
  </button>
<% end %>
```

instead of the `button_to` helper.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply. However, I want some kind of toggle functionality instead of the button straight sending to the database (i.e. the user can choose and press between the different buttons and then once they decided, they can press the submit button and submit the score accordingly. I did a lot of research but seems like there isn't a simple answer.

Comment: Several radio buttons are probably what you're looking for: `<label><input type="radio" name="article[score]" value="1"><img ...></label> <label><input type="radio" name="article[score]" value="2"><img> ...</label> <label><input type="radio" name="article[score]" value="3"><img ...></label>` although you'll need some CSS magic to hide the pickers.

Comment: Thanks so much! I have used the method you suggested together with some jQuery and CSS. Works perfectly.

Answer (score 1):

Overlay a checkbox on each image. Make the label for the checkbox encompass the image so when the image is clicked the checkbox is checked. (Use radio buttons if you want the user to select only one image)

Then when the form is submitted to the controller, the controller can check the `params` to see what image(s) were selected and do whatever it needs to do.

Comment: Hi, I am planning to use the radio buttons as well. But is there a way to change the appearance of the radio button. I know I can use an image tag to tag an image beside the radio buttons but is there a way to actually change the radio button into the actual image so that I only need to click the image. If you know what I mean.

Comment: yes, you could make the radio buttons hidden, then, for example, use js to apply a css border around whichever image is selected.